# How to use double click bid manager(DBM) API in python

Tags: python, google-api, double-click-advertising

I am trying to use the google Double click bid manager (DBM) API, to download reports, I am trying to make this automatic without manual authentication, but all I can find is the GitHub repo for DBM samples https://github.com/googleads/googleads-bidmanager-examples
This sample opens up a browser for manual authentication.
Is there any way to do it automatically using python?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Google Cloud Platform service account for authentication as well.

- Create service account and create/download the JSON key
- Add the service account to the DBM (now Display & Video 360) account you want to access
- Use the Python Google API client library (also see [this Google DV360 tutorial](https://stacktonic.com/article/how-to-activate-and-pause-line-items-in-google-dv-360-using-python), the authentication part is the same):

```
from googleapiclient import discovery
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

# SETTINGS - GOOGLE GENERAL
GOOGLE_JSON_KEYFILE = "<your-keyfile>.json" # Google Cloud Platform Service Account JSON keyfile

# SETTINGS - GOOGLE DV360 API
GOOGLE_DV360_API_VERSION = 'v1'
GOOGLE_DV360_API_SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/display-video']

# Google D&V360 API service
def get_dv360_service():
    credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(
        GOOGLE_JSON_KEYFILE,
        scopes=GOOGLE_DV360_API_SCOPES)

    return discovery.build('displayvideo', GOOGLE_DV360_API_VERSION, credentials=credentials, cache_discovery=False)

dv360_service = get_dv360_service()

#dv360_service.-> get your reports
```